# Why is this button is not centered?

Tags: php, html, css

i'm working in a WordPress theme and i have this button:

[image]

"Ver mais"

I tried everything but he's not getting centered without breaking the content above.

Before, this button used to call "Comprar", but i need to change it with CSS since i only had to change in this specific page, so this is what i did:

```
.dhvc-woo-info .button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart {
  visibility: hidden; /*here was the old button with his original content.*/
} 
.dhvc-woo-info .button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart:after {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-width: 1px;
  content:'VER MAIS'; 
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;

}
```

I just need the button to get centered and i dont know how :(

if needed, this is the php code that shows "Em até 10x de R$: 99,00....."

```
if ($hide_price !== '0') :
    $output_price .= '<div class="dhvc-woo-price dhvc-woo-span6">';
    $output_price .= $product->get_price_html ();
    $output_price .= '<div class="teste">Em até 10x de';
    $output_price .= '<span class="teste2">';
    $output_price .= ' R$: ';
    $output_price .=  number_format($totalPrice, 2, ',', '.');
    $output_price .= '</span>';
    $output_price .= '<br>Ou à vista com 10% de desconto por';
    $output_price .= '<span class="teste3">';
    $output_price .= ' R$: ';
    $output_price .=  number_format($aVista, 2, ',', '.');
    $output_price .= '</span>';
    $output_price .= '</div>';
    $output_price .= '</div>';
endif;
```

I'm sorry guys, I know this is kinda dumb and that I may be wrong by using after with content but its what I found to work better since I cant edit WordPress HTML without losing future updates.

Comment: Can u try and set `margin: 60px auto 0 auto;` and `width:auto;` to `.dhvc-woo-info .button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart:after`

Comment: Apply margin:0 auto; to the container of this button. Make sure that the container is block level element.
CSS:
div {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:10%;
 }
 div:after {
        your current CSS code goes here
}

HTML:
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

you can use container div with 100% width which will be equal to the box, then you can use margin: 60px auto; width: 30% for the button

which will have 60px margin from top and bottom and auto margin from left and right; button width as 30% of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who tried to help me.
I wasnt able to use html and the css sugestions just kept broking the style so i decided to quit using content and did some magic so now its fine. Thanks everyone anyway <3